# Spring cloud stream Kafka Reactive stream partition assignment

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

How does spring cloud stream assign multiple Kafka partitions to reactive streams belonging to same consumer group?

I noticed that if I use plain non-reactive stream listener each thread gets assigned to one partition, depending on the consumer concurrency configuration. Whereas, in case of stream (Flux input) I did not notice any such parrallel  behavior. It seems like only one stream is defined to process messages from all the partitions.

My expectation is to have separate stream for each Kafka topic partition, even on same node backed up by different threads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing it up. I've created an issue to track this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/980